# Handling multiple features in a single event

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have been coding my bot for over a year now, but I am still struggling on handling multiple bot features within one event. Example:

```js
// message event

//advert protection
const checkAdve = db.prepare('.......').get();
if (!checkAdve') {
   return;
}

// economy
const checkEco = db.prepare('.......').get();
if (!checkEco') {
   return;
}
```

This is just a rough example (I don't have my code at hand at the moment) but essentially the issue here is that if `checkAdve` returns, then the economy feature never runs as advert returned. I know I could do

```js
if (checkAdve) {
// do stuff
}
```

but that is not always possible with some of my features.

I am still learning 'discord.js' and would appreciate if someone could teach me how you handle things like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working inside a listener, it have its own scope. While using `return` you are leaving out the scope and stopping further execution. You need to create additional scope to handle your logic, for example with function.

```js
function checkAdve(db) {
  const adveResult = db.prepare('.......').get();
  if(!adveResult) return false;
  return adveResult;
}
```

Then in your message event listener you can use your function:

```js
client.on('message', (message) => { 
  checkAdve(db);
}
```

Comment: I can not thank you enough, honestly, I have been suffering from this issue for so long!

Answer (score 1):

You could write multiple functions that contain your features and then call them in the event.

Example:

```js
const checkEco = (Pass, Parameters, Here, GuildID) => {
    const checkingEco = db.prepare('.......').get();
    if (!checkingEco ') {
        return;
    }
}

client.on('message', message => {
    checkEco(Passing, Parameters, Here, message.guild.id)
})
```